# How to connect servlet

Tags: java, android

I am doing client server process. I dont know how to connect with Servlet . In servlet i have JDBC that collects data from oracle. I want to connect servlet and to show all the details from oracle database in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android offers the [`HttpClient` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) to fire and handle HTTP requests. There are [several snippets](http://www.google.com/search?q=httpclient+site%3Aandroidsnippets.org) on [androidsnippets.org](http://androidsnippets.org). Here's an example of firing a [HTTP GET request](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/82/):

```
public static InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {  
  InputStream content = null;  
  try {  
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));  
    content = response.getEntity().getContent();  
  } catch (Exception e) {  
    Log.("[GET REQUEST]", "Network exception", e);  
  }  
  return content;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this may be useful for me. can you attach some example code (Example tutorials) for interaction between servlet. I am new to android, still it remains confusion.

Comment: In your servlet you just write the desired data to the outputstream or writer of the `HttpServletResponse`. It'll be available inside the `InputStream` in the above code snippet. To ease processing of the data, you may consider to send the data in a fixed format like XML or JSON so that you can use ready-to-use parsers to convert between `InputStream` or `String` and Javabean class(es).

Answer (score 0):

I did customize this code and using it as generic web service caller class.

you can use this customized version of WebService class
-> http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13849473/WebService.java

p.s. the original source is from;
http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/04/30/android-accessing-restfull-web-services-using-json/